# Drupal deleting/updating wrong row in database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have a set of items that I can edit and delete with a form. Now, all itms are displayed in a list as fieldsets. The fieldsets are created with this method:

```
 $venues = db_query('SELECT vid, name, address, postcode, city FROM venues v WHERE v.uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $user->uid));
 if($venues->rowCount() != 0) {
   foreach($venues as $venue) {
     $page['venue_editing_form'][] = drupal_get_form('venue_editor_form', $venue->vid, $venue->name, $venue->address, $venue->postcode, $venue->city); 
   }
 }
```

Then the form is created with this function:

```
function venue_editor_form($form, &$form_state, $vid, $vname, $vadd, $vpostc, $vcity) {
$form['#prefix'] = '<div class="vedit">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t($vname),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('venue-edit')),
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['venue_name'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Venue name:'),
  '#description' => t('Enter the venue name.'),
  '#default_value' => $vname,
  '#attributes' => array('onfocus' => 'this.value=""')
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['address'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Address:'),
  '#description' => t('The address of this venue.'),
  '#default_value' => $vadd,
  '#attributes' => array('onfocus' => 'this.value=""')
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['postcode'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Postcode'),
  '#description' => t('Enter the postcode for this event, so planB can position it on the map'),
  '#default_value' => $vpostc,
  '#attributes' => array('onfocus' => 'this.value=""', 'onblur' => 'getLatLong(this)')
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['city'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('City'),
  '#description' => t('The city this venue is in.'),
  '#default_value' => $vcity,
  '#attributes' => array('onfocus' => 'this.value=""')
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['edit_submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit changes'),
  '#validate' => array('venue_creation_form_validate')
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['delete_venue'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Delete venue'),
  '#submit' => array('venue_form_delete')
);
$form['edit_fieldset_'.$vname]['venueid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $vid
);
return $form;
```

}

And one of the submit handlers:

```
function venue_form_delete($form, &$form_state) {
  $deleted = db_delete('venues')
    ->condition('vid', $form['#venueid'], '=')
    ->execute();
    drupal_set_message('Venue deleted successfully.');
}
```

Now, the problem is that no matter which venue's deletion button I press, Drupal always deletes the first one of the ones in the list. `$form['#venueid']` is always set to the first venue in the list in the submit handler, for some reason, but if I print a message when the forms are being generated, each of the forms has a different ID, as it should be.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Where's vid coming from? Do you mean nid?

Comment: vid is the venue id it comes from a database query to get the details of all the venues. Then, I use a foreach loop to go through all the results and drupal_get_form('venue_editor_form', $venue->vid ...)

Comment: Rereading the question, could it be that you have one form, with multiple fieldsets and multiple Submit/Delete buttons (i.e. one fieldset per venue)?

Comment: There are multiple fieldsets with multiple delete/update buttons but there is one form per fieldset. The forms get created by getting the venues from the database and in a foreach loop calling drupal_get_form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my co-workers ran into this a few weeks ago.  The reason you are having this problem is because you are trying to load the same form multiple times on one page with different data.  It seems like this should work, however it doesn't because all the forms end up with the same token / ID.  When you submit each form the system doesnt know which one you really clicked on and can not take the appropriate action.

There are 2 approaches to solve this problem:

1) Rework your forms so that it is all handled with 1 form instead of multiple

2) use [hook_forms(...)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7) to create a 'base form' and then generate unique forms for each venue that map to the 'base form'.  This will make sure each form gets a unique ID without having to write forms for each one.

I dont have a drupal 7 example but here is a page that shows how to solve your problem for drupal 6 using hook_forms http://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-6-multiple-instances-same-form-one-page  .  You should be able to apply the same technique

I havent tested this code, but this is the basic idea:

Modify your get_form to use a unique id

```
foreach($venues as $venue) {
     $page['venue_editing_form'][] = drupal_get_form('venue_editor_form_'. $venue->vid, $venue->vid, $venue->name, $venue->address, $venue->postcode, $venue->city); 
   }
```

Impliment hook_forms

```
function MODULENAME_forms($form_id) {
  $forms = array();
  if (preg_match('/venue_editor_form_/', $form_id) {
    $forms[$form_id] = array(
      'callback' => 'venue_editor_form',
    );
  }
  return $forms;
}
```

And then i think you have to modify your form's submit parameter to make sure they all get routed to the same submit handler.  Though it does look like you are adding different submits per button so you might not have to do anything there

```
$form['#submit'] => array('venue_editing_form_submit');
```

You might also have to do the same with the validate functions.

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. Drupal cannot discern between submissions with the same form ID and that's why it was deleting the wrong venue! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you try to pass the venueid value through the form processing without using an explicit value field:

```
$form['#venueid'] = $vid;
```

This just assigns a value to a 'made up' form property (leading '#'), which normally does not exist. Try to use an explicit [value field type](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#val) instead:

```
$form['venueid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $node->vid
);
```

With this, the vid should be available in your submit functions just like any other form value, i.e. in `$form_state['values']`:

```
function venue_form_delete($form, &$form_state) {
  $deleted = db_delete('venues')
    ->condition('vid', $form_state['values']['venueid'], '=')
    ->execute();
    drupal_set_message('Venue deleted successfully.');
}
```

Note the removal of the '#' character - a leading '#' indicates form (and form element) properties, which Drupal will try to interprete during form processing, and '#venueid' is not a defined property.

Comment: Using custom FAPI properties is very much standard practice (dozens of contributed modules do so, e.g. Date's `#date_format` key). The only issue with using a `#`'d property in the array is the potential for a collision with an existing named property. This can be avoided by prefixing the name of the property with the name of the module responsible for implementing it, e.g. `#mymodule_venueid`. Other than that this method is 100% valid and will not be causing the described problems.

Comment: @Clive: You are right, many contrib modules do this one way or the other, but I would not call it 'standard practice'. Using FAPI properties like this means relying on an undocumented functionality (which could change anytime), instead of using the official, documented and recommended alternative (in form of the '#value' type element). So my suggestion aimed at trying the 'normal' way first, before going on a hunt for a problem with an undocumented 'feature'.

Comment: @Clive: And to avoid misunderstandings - with 'undocumented', I do not mean the concept of custom FAPI properties in itself. If one wants to extend FAPI functionality from a custom module, e.g. by providing a new element type, he can and should use custom properties if needed (like the date module does with `#date_format`). But this usage of properties is aimed at form element processing/handling during the lifetime of a form, not at passing values to submit functions.

Comment: I do agree with you for the most part, except to say that Drupal *core* actually uses this method to pass arbitrary data to submit/validation functions. The best example is the node edit form which keeps hold of a `#node` property throughout the lifecycle of the form and continually refers back to it. Again though, I do agree with what you're saying. Perhaps the best compromise would be for Drupal to actually produce documentation about this sort of thing. Then at least there would be a definitive 'Drupal' answer to the question

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as it was pointed out that didn't make any difference. I've changed my code to reflect a more 'standardised' technique. Thanks to both of you for taking the time to look into it.

Comment: I added the changes I made and full code in case you see where I've been going wrong... Possibly on $page['venue_editing_form'][]?